# How did Harry Potter breathe on the Thestral journey to London?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures

In *Harry Potter and The Order of the Phoenix*, Harry and his friends travel from Hogwarts to The Ministry of Magic in London to attempt to save Sirius Black from Lord Voldemort and to get there they use Thestrals. From a question here

[How fast do Thestrals fly?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142418/how-fast-do-thestrals-fly)

The rough estimate for speed for the journey is 200mph+.  If we take this as being roughly correct, how did they manage to breath at this speed for a 2 hour or more journey?  We know there was, for example, the bubble-head charm that could have possibly worked but it isn’t mentioned in the book nor shown in the movie. Has there been any mention elsewhere as to how it was done, e.g. Pottermore?

Comment: I believe the traditional answer to questions like this is " A wizard did it".

Comment: I am sure you are probably right mate! . I just wondered if anyone knew anything different!

Comment: Pure magic, I think ;D

Comment: @DJClayworth or maybe a witch?

Comment: As an ancient wizard once said, [used the force, he did](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126465/how-did-obi-wan-survive-the-trip-to-naboo#comment316449_126465)

Answer (score 3):

Wizards and witches are more resistant than normal people. They could fly on a broom without any problem flying on an animal are no more troublesome than a broom flight.

Also looking for fights in an open cabin I found this: [Nieuport-Delage Sesquiplan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nieuport-Delage_Sesquiplan)

A flight with a speed of 200 mph and with a distance travelled more that the question so normal humans don't  have any problems in these conditions.

Comment: I think the simplest answer here is that such a thing is perfectly possible for muggles, and hence perfectly possible for wizards, notwithstanding that you could simply shield your face with a sleeve or the edge of a robe.

Comment: would magic not be useful?

Comment: Brooms are used to long distance travel so maybe here are spells to protect of the wind like a window but we don´t know if students have access to that spells.  The bubble head spell that are mentioned in the question could be useful but maybe not all the students know how to make it.

Answer (score -3):

I would like to answer with this: magic

Otherwise, we’d have to start asking how wizards can use sticks of wood to make objects fly around.

Although, I do want to theorise that Thestrals probably don’t travel at 200mph in the conventional sense. Mathematically, that is distance over time, yes. But it’s more likely that Thestrals warp space time rather that physically move super fast. This is purely theory.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back up this contention?